# Key not valid for use in specified state ? Reporting Services 2008

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssrs-2008

I'm receiving this error when trying to see a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if this happened to you, you've probably has just changed the password of the user that runs the Reporting Services.

You probably can't access the Report Manager either.

Scenario:

Windows 2003 Server /
Reporting Services 2008

The way I fixed this was the following:

1. Open a console (cmd)
2. Typed in this: rskeymgmt -d
3. Press Y and hit enter.
4. Now you have access to the report manager.
5. Go to the Data Source Properties and review your data sources: in my case i just fixed one data source (so take in advice this fix if you have plenty data sources). In my case I set that use the credentials: user and password for the user that runs the reports.
6. That's it.

Source:
[This page helped me](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-reporting/3389/Error-Key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state)

Hope it helps