# How do I get back to my Reporting Services Data?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, encryption

I have almost exactly [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762658/key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state-reporting-services-2008). I say, almost exactly because the answer that worked for this gentleman did nothing whatsoever for me. I can open my own database and see all of the lovely RS data sitting there staring at me but the actual Reporting Services installation still can't. This all came about because of precisely what he said. We accidentally left the password policy on on the Reporting Services account and it expired. When I changed it the whole thing went kaputt. I'm still getting the "key cannot be used in current state" error message even after dropping all encrypted data from the RS installation. I have no access to the Report Manager to reset encrypted information. Has anyone got any suggestions?

EDIT: In continuing my research I found [this suggestion](http://www.willasrari.com/blog/key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-state/000151.aspx). It's not that.

Comment: +1 for using the German word *"kaput"* (it's actually spelled kaputt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... here's the thing.

I eventually tried creating a whole new user to take charge of the SSRS operations. I also remembered to update those details on our live data server. (I did this first and it failed to work as it was still telling me the key could not be used then.)

I guess that there must be something that prevents the reassignment of the SSRS gofer account's password. The new user is set up identically and works perfectly. So that's what cleared it up for me but I'm a little irritated that I still don't know exactly why...